# Как изменить адрес публикации приложения AspNetCore2.2. после публикации в локальную папку

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

выполнил команду publish из VS2017 для публикации приложения в локальную папку. 
Для запуска приложения в режиме отладки использую команду

```
dotnet WebApiSwc.dll --environment "Development"
```

все запускается правильно, но не понимаю откуда берется адрес публикации localhost:5000

Файла launchSettings.json в папке публикации нет.
Подскажите как изменить этот адрес?

> PublishProfiles FolderProfile.pubxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>0939d51d-2e92-4cb5-8a21-68e324cca18f</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно передать еще 1 переменную с указанием адресса `--server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5000`

dotnet WebApiSwc.dll --environment "Development" --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5555